# How to Copy and Replace into List

Tags: c#, linq, generics, .net-core

How do I copy update and replace an existing list *(this will delete all items and replace with new class)*? Both lists have already been declared.

```
public class ProductType1
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
}

public class ProductType2
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductBarCodeNumber{ get; set; }
}

List<ProductType1> producttype1 = new List<ProductType1>()
List<ProductType2> producttype2 = new List<ProductType2>()
```

**Purpose**: Delete all of ProductType1, and Copy All ProductType2 into ProductType1, excluding ProductBarCodeNumber.

project ElectronicsStore test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using *Linq* *projection*

```
producttype1 = producttype2.Select(x => new ProductType1() 
                                            { ProductId = x.ProductId,
                                              ProductName = x.ProductName,
                                              ProductDescription = x.ProductDescription})
                           .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, and I assume this will work if producttype1 already has values it will delete and take values from producttype2 with projection, appreciate it

Comment: @JoeMiller yes on all counts

Comment: @JoeMiller, no, projection will create new instance of `List<ProductType1>`. with new instances of `productType1`. Original instance will be garbage collected. You can simply check by saving original list to the temp variable before projection.